# SRFI 105 as a Racket language, how to parse include files?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm porting SRFI 105 "Curly infix" to Racket.

I wrote a "reader" that works and the SRFI 105 is packaged with a REPL that works already with little change (only one line modified as far as ia can remember) but I'm facing a difficulty, being not easy with the Racket ecosytem of building lanaguages:

-first how can I make my implementation parse, not only the main program, but possibly include files? i.e if I have a (include "infix-file.scm") I want the reader/parser to load and parse it before the expansion step which is too late and more difficult

Here the beginning of my specialised code (the rest is as the official SRFI 105) file SRFI-105.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/strip-context)
 
(provide (rename-out [literal-read read]
                     [literal-read-syntax read-syntax]))


(define (literal-read in)
  (syntax->datum
   (literal-read-syntax #f in)))
 
(define (literal-read-syntax src in)
  
  (define lst-code (process-input-code-rec in))

  `(module anything racket ,@lst-code))

;; read all the expression of program
;; a tail recursive version
(define (process-input-code-tail-rec in) ;; in: port
  (define (process-input acc)
    (define result (curly-infix-read in))  ;; read an expression
    (if (eof-object? result)
    (reverse acc)
    (process-input (cons result acc))))
  (process-input '()))


  ; ------------------------------
  ; Curly-infix support procedures
  ; ------------------------------
```

and here is an example of source file using it:

```
#lang reader "SRFI-105.rkt"
(- (+ 3 3)
   {2 + 2})

{5 + 2}

(define (fibonacci n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (+ (fibonacci (- n 1)) (fibonacci (- n 2)))))
(fibonacci 7)

(define (fib n)
  (if {n < 2}
      n
      {(fib {n - 1}) + (fib {n - 2})} ))

(fib 11)
```

and the obvious results:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.2 [cs].
Language: reader "SRFI-105.rkt", with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
2
7
13
89
>
```

-second, i know how to make a #lang "my language.rkt" parse the following code but i do not know how to integrate the working SRFI 105 REPL in Racket ecosystem (for now it works in a separate file than parser).

here the official SRFI 105 that already work in Racket with minor changes:

```
  ; --------------
  ; Demo of reader
  ; --------------

(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

;{1 + 1}
;(+ 1 1)
;2
;(define k {1 + 1})
;(define k (+ 1 1))
;#<void>
;k
;k
;2

  ; repeatedly read in curly-infix and write traditional s-expression.
  (define (process-input)
    (let ((result (curly-infix-read)))
      (cond ((not (eof-object? result))
         (let ((rv (eval result ns)))
           (write result) (display "\n")
           (write rv)
           (display "\n"))
         ;; (force-output) ; flush, so can interactively control something else
         (process-input)) ;; no else clause or other
        )))

(process-input)
```

Comment: Why would you want it to also apply to required files? Eg. if you do `(require racket/lists)` from you code, do you really want it to be interpreted as infix? Wouldn't it be better that all files that are infix either have their own `#lang` name which basically is a infix version of `racket` such that you can import both those infix files as well as the standard library files of racket?

Comment: @Sylwester: not require but include. if i include #lang in each file i afraid, as far as i can remember, this will create an isolated set of definitions not visible from the upper ones?

Comment: @Sylwester: i tested to put #lang in each file and it fails because include files are now in their separate namespace and i can not see any definition included.

Comment: I would use `include/reader` to include other files. If the included files themselves use `include` and not `include/reader`, then I'd define my own version of `include` (to shadow the builtin) that expands to `include/reader` using your reader.

Comment: @soegaard yes how can i do it , i do not want to be forced to modify all my source file , they are compatible with other scheme,is there a way to make include/reader be used instead of include for any included files? sorry if you misunderstand my question, question is how to shadow the built in include function?

Comment: @DamienMattei That depends on how you are using your reader.
But experience has taught be, that using `include` rarely works in the Racket eco system in the long run - especially if we are talking about a larger project. I can't recommend enough to use the standard `#lang racket` with `require` instead.

Comment: and if i want to use (include/reader "infix-file.rkt" literal-read-syntax) i have an error unbound variable,how can i export my literal-read-syntax procedure to the included files?

Comment: yes it worked with require and inserting a #lang "srfi-105.rkt" at the top of the required file.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution is to use 'require' instead of 'include' for loading a source file from another and adding one more
#lang reader "SRFI-105.rkt" at the beginning of each loaded file.

example of main file loading another .rkt file

```
#lang reader "SRFI-105.rkt"
(require "examples-curly-infix2.rkt")
(- (+ 3 3)
   {2 + 2})

{5 + 2}

(define (fibonacci n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (+ (fibonacci (- n 1)) (fibonacci (- n 2)))))
(fibonacci 7)

(define (fib n)
  (if {n < 2}
      n
      {(fib {n - 1}) + (fib {n - 2})} ))

(fib 11)
```

and here is the loaded file:

```
#lang reader "SRFI-105.rkt"
{7 * 3}
```

execution will output this:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.2 [cs].
Language: reader "SRFI-105.rkt", with debugging; memory limit:         128 MB.
21
2
7
13
89
```

21 is coming from the 'required' file,
note that instead of include you can not control at which line number the file will be loaded with require (they are loaded at the beginning)